# Undetermined error on Java WS with play framework 2.6.x

Tags: java, playframework, soap-client, ws

when trying to connect to a web service, according to SOAP UI on the image below, I receive an indeterminate error (handshake_failure)

[image: Text]

Could you tell me the source of the error please? thank you

This is my code on play framework 2.6.x

```
public CompletionStage<Result> index() {
    
    final JsonNode task = Json.newObject()
                              .put("idPartenaire"   , "CETEMCO")
                              .put("password"       , "CETEMCO@2020")
                              .put("hmac"           , "5f35c3a156fd71c96961467a945016e22e3c9f34ff17ce4a07728fc9d4e4f645")
                              .put("message"        , "TEST-MESSAGE")
                              .put("messageType"    , "TEST-MESSAGE-TYPE");

    final CompletionStage<WSResponse> eventualResponse = ws.url("https://test.portnet.ma/portnet/PortnetMessageReceiverService?wsdl")                                                                                                                              
                                                           .post(task);
                                                          
                                                           

    return eventualResponse.thenApplyAsync(response -> 
                ok(response.asJson())
                ,httpExecutionContext.current());
}
```